# ctrl in swift language

Tags: swift, character, special-characters

Does swift have special character for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>?
I am attempting to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> string command to telnet server, but I can't find any character to present ctrl on swift.

Any one know about it?
Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl-X is hex code `0x18`.

Comment: Usual control characters can be represented as `"\u{0}"` to `"\u{1f}"` in Swift Strings. (Or you may need to use `"\u{7f}"` as well. But many things depend on how you are sending such bytes. You should better show more context.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rmaddy and OOPer , I post code under here.

```
let commandData = dataWithHexString(hex: "0x18")
let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + 2
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
    self.socket.write(commandData, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
    self.socket.readData(withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
}    

func dataWithHexString(hex: String) -> Data {
    var hex = hex
    var data = Data()
    while(hex.count > 0) {
        let subIndex = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
        let c = String(hex[..<subIndex])
        hex = String(hex[subIndex...])
        var ch: UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: c).scanHexInt32(&ch)
        var char = UInt8(ch)
        data.append(&char, count: 1)
    }
    return data
}
```

Comment: There is a vastly simpler way to do this. Remove your `dataWithHexString` method and replace the first line of code with: `let commandData = Data([ 0x18 ])`.